# How do I make CSS transform: scale work correctly on Chrome?

Tags: css, google-chrome, transform, scale

Hello I am having issues using `transform: scale` in CSS.

I am trying to scale a 1px*1px block by scale(200). I assumed that the block would end up being 200px*200px. This is the case in Firefox, but in Chrome this is not the case.

```css
#wrap {
  position: absolute;
  left: 200px;
  top: 200px;
}
#a {
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  transform: scale(200);
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <div id="a">A</div>
</div>
```

The Chrome devtools show the correct size yet the block is not the correct size.

I am using Windows Display scaling options of 225% `window.devicePixelRatio = 2.25`.
The reason I am mentioning this is because it looks like there is a 25% difference between the size. Also when I turn my window scaling to 200% the block is displaying the correct size.

[image: Devtools highlights the correct size]